# Finding verticies of a polygon given the number of sides?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to a function that will find all the vertices of a polygon given X number of sides and a radius r. My overall goal is to make a circle but since you can only draw straight lines I will have to make a polygon. So all of the polygons are going to be centred on the point (0,0). And I want to find all the coordinates for a polygon with 6 sides and radius that will iterate from .1 to 1.0. This should form a 10 circles inside of each other.
Here is what I have so far:

Here are my errors:

```
52:33: error: variable-sized object ‘vertices’ may not be initialized
57:17: error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘vertices’, which is of non-class type ‘iPoint [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)nVertices) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’
```

My goal for the for loop is to get all the coordinates for a single polygon for the given radius and stick them in the verticies array as a 2 dimensional Point (x coordinate and a y coordinate).

Comment: sorry I just updated my errors

Comment: vertices needs to be declared outside the for loop

Comment: vertices is an array of the coordinates for the polygon.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I will move it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take `Point vertices[nVerticies] = {};` out of the loop (before the `for`).  I would additionally correct `verticies` to `vertices`.  Also, math functions `sin` and `cos` usually work in radians, not degrees.  Finally, the angle increment can't be constant but depend (inversely) on `nVertices`.

Taking all together:

```
double radius = 0.1;
int nVertices = 6;
double angle = pi()*2/nVertices ;
while(radius <= 1.0)
{
     iPoint vertices[nVertices];
     for (int i = 0; i < nVertices; i++)
     {
          double x = 0 + radius * sin(i * angle);
          double y = 0 + radius * cos(i * angle);
          vertices[i]= iPoint(x,y) ;
     }
     radius = radius + 0.1;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get the same compiler errors.

Comment: @user977154  I've been updating the answer as I found items.  Now it's good except that instead of `pi()` you could need to define your own constant  (`3.14159265359`)

Comment: 53:33: error: variable-sized object ‘vertices’ may not be initialized
58:17: error: request for member ‘insert’ in ‘vertices’, which is of non-class type ‘iPoint [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)nVertices) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)]’

Comment: @user977154  If you still are having trouble, please include your `#include`s.

Comment: That is exactly what i was wanting

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any advice?

The angular distance between two points on a regular flat 2D polygon is `2pi / N`

#### Update due to comment

I'd write it slightly differently.

```
 #include <math.h> // for M_PI

 void circle_points(
     double const radius,
     int const n_points,
     std::vector<Point<double>> &out_points )
 {
     out_points.resize(n_points);

     double const angular_distance = M_PI / (double)n_points;
     for( int i = 0; i < n_points; i++ ) {
          double const x = radius * sin(i * angular_distance);
          double const y = radius * cos(i * angular_distance);
          out_points[i] = Point<double>(x,y);
     }
 }
 
 void concentric_circles(
     double const radius_start,
     double const radius_end,
     int const n_circles,
     int const n_points_per_circle,
     std::vector<std::vector<Point<double>> &out_circles )
 {
     out_circles.resize(n_circles);
     double const radius_increment = (radius_end - radius_start) / n_circles;
     for( int i = 0; i < n_circles; i++ ) {
         circle_points(
             radius_start + radius_increment*i,
             n_points_per_circle,
             out_circles[i] );
     }
 }
```

I'm passing the vectors by reference here to avoid deep copies when entering / leaving the function scopes.

Comment: I updated the code, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @user977154  Yes, that's what he/she's talking about.

Comment: @user977154: Yes. But there's still the issue with the change of radius. Unless you were to create a spiral you want to keep the radius constant.

Comment: well i believe that I do want a spiral because there is supposed to be a lot of circles wihin each other which kind of make a 2d spiral

Comment: @user977154: Well, a polygon is a closed loop, so you cannot just append points of another circle to the same list, without keeping track of where one circle ends and the next starts.

Comment: @user977154: I slightly added to my code example, showcasing how to make a vector of a vector of Points.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like vertices to be a static array and initialize it , declare 'nVertices' as a macro or const int.

`const int nVertices  = 6;`